# Passing C arguments by dragging to a command line application in macOS

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop

I have created a command-line application for MACOS with XCODE.

It is a simple C program that accepts a filename passed to command line as ARGV.

My question is: how can I enable the drag and drop on the created executable, so that I can pass the ARGC parameter simply by dragging the fine to the executable?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a simple executable command-line program, macOS doesn't know what you want to do when you just drag and drop a file onto it. What you need to do is create a proper macOS application.

To do so:

1. Open *Automator.app*
2. Create a new *Application*
3. From the left, drag *Run Shell Script* to the right pane
4. Select *Pass input → as arguments*
5. As content of the script, enter:

   ```
   /path/to/test "$@"
   ```

   where `/path/to/test` is the actual path to your C executable.
6. Save the application anywhere you like.

Once you drag a file onto the newly created `.app`, it will simply call your C executable and pass the filename as first argument, or, in the case of many files, all of them.

---

To give an example, I made a small Python script `~/Desktop/test.py`, which needs to be executable (`chmod +x ~/Desktop/test.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print("Running a script with " + str(sys.argv[1:])
```

I then created the following Automator action:

[image]

What this does is capture the output of the Python script and show a notification with that output once the script is finished. So when I drag the `test.py` file onto the `.app`, I get this output:

[image]